# How does gcc know which lib to use?

Tags: gcc

In my PC, there are two directories under  /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/

4.4  &  4.4.3

How does gcc know which lib to use?  Is there a config file or the search path is build in?

If 4.4.3 is used, could i change to 4.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Commonly you have a symlink in `/usr/bin/gcc` pointing to the actual gcc version you want to use. E.g. `/usr/bin/gcc` -> `/usr/bin/gcc-4.3`
Change this symlink to another version of gcc to use it.
Creating symlinks can be done using `ln -s gcc gcc-4.3`

Comment: There is only /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 in /usr/bin. But has 4.4.3 & 4.4 in /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/. How to change?

Comment: Try to set the environment variables `COMPILER_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. Don't forget to add `/lib` and `/usr/lib` to your `LIBRARY_PATH` if you override it.